# In https workflow, how client knows whether its connected to correct server not malicious?

Tags: ssl, https

Was reading HTTPS workflow and would like to understand more about it.

Client ---> Malicious Server (instead of actual server)

When Client connects to server there can be possibility that it connects to malicious server and that server represents the certificate on behalf of Actual Server, how client knows whether its genuine server or not?

Comment: I am not sure. I think that the cert is bound to the domain it is used on.

Comment: Certificate validation in HTTPS is about being connected to the *"expected"* server. Being *"malicious"* is a different concept, i.e. the expected server can well be malicious. HTTPS protects against man in the middle attacks but makes no statements about the server being malicious or not. HTTPS can well be used to server malware etc.